# Firestore document deletion timer function with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

i need to run a python script from remote server to firebase data manteinance,  i want to delete all documents on a collection called "messages" **every 24 hours**
the google sample shows this code:

```
def delete_collection(coll_ref, batch_size):
docs = coll_ref.limit(10).get()
deleted = 0

for doc in docs:
    print(u'Deleting doc {} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
    doc.reference.delete()
    deleted = deleted + 1

if deleted >= batch_size:
    return delete_collection(coll_ref, batch_size)
```

but i dont know how to implement this to make the daily deletion, could someone show me how to do this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not to use Cloud Functions?

Comment: i really don't know how to create the function and implent this!